# Regex "or" within express route string containing express param

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I'm trying to do this, but it's not working.

```
app.get("/|/:enter");
```

I want one `app.get` to route both `/` as well as `/:enter`.

**update**

Both

```
app.get("/|/:enter");
```

and

```
app.get("/:enter|/");
```

do not send the full "enter" string to the params middleware parse, the `id` variable is just "e".

Comment: [`app.get`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) can take a regex for the route...

Comment: yeah but not so well when there's a param invloved

Comment: Have you tried using a capture-group in the regex? Something like `/^\/(\w+)?/` as in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't combined regex and params XD

Answer (score 0):

Needed to be

```
app.get("/:enter|/")
```

*reversed

It was somehow overwriting all the other routes the other way.

Comment: I might be because your original regex was invalid with an unescaped forward slash.

Comment: This is my regex `var regex = new RegExp('^('+params.join("|")+')$',"i");` anything wrong with it?

Comment: for some reason the `id` tends to get stripped to one character in `params`

Answer (score 0):

`app.get(/^(\/|\/:enter)$/, function(){...});`

docs: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB

Comment: If params involved, writing two `app.get` may be a better choice

Answer (score 0):

In you case you may mark `:enter` as optional parameter like that:

```
app.get('/:enter?')
```

Also you may use [express-route-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-route-params) to apply validation to the `:enter` parameter so that the route matches only if `enter` satisfies certain criteria. For example:

`app.param('enter', /^\w+$/)`

This way you sort of combine regexp with params ;)